# how to find the surface area of a unit disk

Tags: partial-derivative, graphing-functions, surface-integrals

Suppose $z$ is a function for which $ \lvert \partial z$/ $\partial x \rvert$ and $\lvert \partial z/ \partial y \rvert$ are both at most $1$. How large could the surface area of the graph of $z$ be above the unit disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the surface area is given,

$$\int_{r\le 1} \sqrt{1+(z_x')^2 + (z_y')^2} ~dS
\le \int_{r\le 1} \sqrt3~ dS = \sqrt3 \pi$$

Thus, the largest surface area is $\sqrt3\pi $.

Comment: when I do the integral, is it not a double integral? $dr d \theta$? So what makes it not multiple by $2 \pi$

Comment: @user702795 - The double integral is simply over a unit disk, whose area is $\pi$. ($2\pi$ is normally for circumference.)

Comment: Of course that this upper bound is best possible is seen by taking $z=x+y$.